# mark rows that contains string

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I struggle to find a way to mark rows in my dataframe has "string" values.

The dataframe

```
data = {'c1':[1,'as.df',1,1,], 'c2':['a90sff',1,1,1], 'c3':[1,1,1,1], 'reject':['','','','']}
test = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

**I'd like the output has 'Yes' on row 1 and row 2 on the 'reject' column**

The real data has thousands of rows and lots of columns so I hope to use loop.

Comment: What `dtype` do the columns end up having? `object`? Why do you need to do this? It seems odd, a bit of a red flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `to_numeric` after that with `any`

```
test.iloc[:,:-1].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').isnull().any(1).map({True:'Yes',False:'No'})
Out[94]: 
0    Yes
1    Yes
2     No
3     No
dtype: object
```

Comment: @Osca check any true per row